# Embed Azure blob pdf file in iframe with google gview

Tags: azure, pdf, iframe, google-drive-api, azure-blob-storage

I have pdf file stored in azure blob service at [this URL](https://hoxrostorage.blob.core.windows.net/hoxro/Matter_545/266408d1-309c-4258-808e-6bccdfc840c8.pdf?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=x8VhYOUGSNp9AJfV%2BT%2BybcBkPQknqNXdolq4Xo0ZAXU%3D&se=2016-06-29T20%3A58%3A52Z&sp=r&rsct=application%2Fpdf).

I can download it normally from browser from this URL.

Now i want to embed this pdf into html page using google gview.

**I have typed:**

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://hoxrostorage.blob.core.windows.net/hoxro/Matter_545/266408d1-309c-4258-808e-6bccdfc840c8.pdf?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=x8VhYOUGSNp9AJfV%2BT%2BybcBkPQknqNXdolq4Xo0ZAXU%3D&se=2016-06-29T20%3A58%3A52Z&sp=r&rsct=application%2Fpdf&embedded=true" width="400px" height="300px"  />
```

**It shows me:**

[image]

**Please note:**

In Azure blob storage my pdf's **content type** is set to **application/pdf**

[image]

I have already checked so many post's from many location but not able to come to any conclusion.

**Could anyone please point me to the right direction, that what is going on here?**

Comment: You have an embedded url within a url, with querystrings within querystrings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you realized it, but your url contains a querystring, which in turn contains a querystring. A snippet:

```
src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?
url=https://hoxrostorage.blob.core.windows.net/hoxro/Matter_545/266408d1-309c-4258-808e-6bccdfc840c8.pdf?
sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=x8VhYOUGSNp9AJfV%2BT%2BybcBkPQknqNXdolq4Xo0ZAXU%3D&se=2016-06-29T20%3A58%3A52Z&sp=r&rsct=application%2Fpdf
&embedded=true"
```

Prior to `&embedded=true`, the rest is the querystring for your blob (which in turn contains a querystring to deal with the Shared Access Signature).

You'll need to encode the embedded blob url , so that the URL parses correctly.

I don't know if that will solve your embedded-preview problem, but at least it will correct your URL formatting.

Comment: You got me. embedded blob url needs to be encoded. got the preview.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

this code is working for me

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=<<previewUri>>" 
        frameborder="no" style="width:100%;height:500px"></iframe>

var blobUri=$"{blob.Uri}{sasToken}";

var previewUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(blobUri);
```

this previewUri will use in the iframe

[View result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZrqJ.png)